# jQuery on click reveal and toggle

Tags: jquery, button

I am working on a WordPress site. I have two "Learn More" links on my page. When either one is clicked I would like them to revile the corresponding paragraph above. Currently clicking either or reveals both. It would also be super helpful to have the link text change from "Learn More" to "Close" on click as well.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".learnMore").on("click", function(e) {
        var $a = $(this).toggleClass("is-active")
        $a.text(function(i, t) {
            return t === 'Learn More' ? 'Close' : 'Learn More';
        });
        $( "p" ).siblings( ".reveal" ).slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

```css
.hide-mobile {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-one">
<h2>Header One</h2>
<p class="hide-mobile reveal">Etiam ut vehicula velit. Cras ut ipsum id tortor ultrices iaculis. Donec sodales ultricies urna vitae porta.</p>
<a class="button" href="/link-url/">Button One</a>
<a class="learnMore mobile">Learn More</a>
</div>

<div class="box-two">
<h2>Header Two</h2>
<p class="hide-mobile reveal">Morbi et varius elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.</p>
<a class="button" href="/link-url-two/">Button Two</a>
<a class="learnMore mobile">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are selecting everything try this:

```
    $("document").on("click", ".learnMore", function (e) {
        var $learnmore = $(e.currentTarget);
        $learnmore.toggleClass("is-active");
        $learnmore.html($learnmore.hasClass('is-active') ? 'Close' : 'Learn More');
        $learnmore.prev(".reveal").slideToggle(10);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you're changing *all* the `.learnMore` and `.reveal` elements when any one of them is clicked.

To fix this use the `this` keyword within the event handler to reference the specific element which raised the event. From there you can traverse the DOM using `prev()` to get the related `.reveal` element to toggle.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".learnMore").on("click", function(e) {
    var $a = $(this).toggleClass("is-active")
    $a.text(function(i, t) {
      return t === 'Learn More' ? 'Close' : 'Learn More';
    });
    $a.prev(".reveal").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-mobile {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Header One</h2>
<p class="hide-mobile reveal">Etiam ut vehicula velit. Cras ut ipsum id tortor ultrices iaculis. Donec sodales ultricies urna vitae porta. </p>
<a class="learnMore mobile">Learn More</a>

<h2>Header Two</h2>
<p class="hide-mobile reveal">Morbi et varius elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.</p>
<a class="learnMore mobile">Learn More</a>
```

Also note that you were telling the `slideToggle()` to complete in 10 milliseconds which is too fast for it to be visible, so I slowed it down to 300ms.

Comment: If I where to have another link (lets say a button) above the learn more link how could I edit the jquery code? I believe it has something to do with the $a.prev(".reveal").slideToggle(500);

Comment: In that case you should put each block of elements in a container and use `siblings()`. If you can't do that then a workaround would be `$a.prevAll('.reveal').first().slideToggle(500);`, but it's not pretty

Comment: Hi Roy, Thanks for all your help with this so far. I have slightly changed the question and included warping the elements in a container and using siblings(). However I am still having problems getting it working. I don't believe I'm using the siblings() selector properly.

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question for this as you've changed the original purpose and more people will then see it

Comment: I believe its still the same question with just a small tweak. Can you please help me out?